# Actionbar custom drawable menuIcon not centered

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to add a custom Drawable which extends `Drawable` to my actionBar. This needs to be a custom drawable, since I want to draw on top of a supplied icon (but that's not the issue).

I've added the icon to the menu in my activity like so:

```
BadgedIconDrawable drawable = new BadgedIconDrawable(getContext())
    .setIcon(icon);
mMenu.add(0, menuItemId, 0, "")
    .setIcon(drawable)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

In the `BadgedIconDrawable` I take a bitmap for the Icon which I then draw on the canvas:

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon.getBitmap(), null, new Rect(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight), mIconPaint);
}
```

Where the width and height are 24dp, which seems to be the right size for the icon.

The problem is that unlike a regular drawable that's passed to the `setIcon` for the `mMenu`, it doesn't seem to align correctly. I can't find how to get it aligned to the center. Image below illustrates the issue. The middle Icon is set through the `BadgedIconDrawable`.

[image: Incorrectly aligned toolbar icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

While the below snippet worked, I soon figured this would only work for the toolbar. Not anymore when used in a regular ImageView. So the trick is to use a `Rect` as to where the bitmap should be drawn. This would have the regular bounds, but when it should be translated, tell the custom Drawable to do so, by modifying the `Rect` like so:

```
// On the fragment/activity create the Drawable, translate it and add to the menu.

public void addBadgedActionBarButton(Drawable icon, int color, String badgeLabel, int menuItemId) {
    if (mMenu == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("mMenu = null, Are you sure you are calling addActionBarButton from initMenu()?");
    } else {
        BadgedIconDrawable drawable = new BadgedIconDrawable(getContext());
        drawable.translate(-drawable.getWidth() / 2, -drawable.getHeight() / 2, drawable.getWidth() / 2, drawable.getHeight() / 2)
                .setIcon(icon);

        mMenu.add(Menu.NONE, menuItemId, Menu.NONE, "")
                .setIcon(drawable)
                .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    }
}

// In the BadgedIconDrawable have a function that sets the mDstRect to the translated Rect.

public BadgedIconDrawable translate(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    mDstRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    return this;
}

// In the BadgedIconDrawable draw function use the mDstRect to draw on the correct position.

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon.getBitmap(), null, mDstRect, mIconPaint);
}
```

---

With some wild guessing I managed to try to add a negative top and left, which seems to place it in the correct spot. This seems to do the trick.

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    int halfWidth = mWidth / 2;
    int halfHeight = mHeight / 2;
    canvas.drawBitmap(mIcon.getBitmap(), null, new Rect(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, halfWidth, halfHeight), mIconPaint);
}
```